# Multivariable calculus: what principle is this step based on?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

The background is that I was asked to solve the following problem using Green's formula

> $L$ is a Jordan curve (smooth and closed) which encloses the origin point in $xOy$ plane. Caculate this integral
>   $$I=\oint_L \frac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\left[(x\sin y-y\cos y)dx+(x\cos y+y\sin y)dy \right]$$
>   in the **counter-clockwise** direction.

Let $P,Q$ denote the $x,y$ components respectively, and it is easy to see $-P'_{y}+Q'_{x}=0$. However, since the origin is a singularity point, we can't apply Green's formula directly on the area enclosed by $L$. So we consider a small circle $\Gamma:x^2+y^2=\epsilon^2$ which is enclosed by $L$. After some simple adjustment we have
$$I=\oint_\Gamma \frac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\left[(x\sin y-y\cos y)dx+(x\cos y+y\sin y)dy \right]\quad\text{(in the clockwise direction)}$$
I'll skip all the complicated calculations here. Finally I got
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\epsilon\cos\theta}\cos(\epsilon\sin\theta)d\theta$$
and I couldn't proceed any further. However when I looked it up in the answerbook, it said, without explanation, that I should let $\epsilon\to 0^+$ and hence
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}1d\theta=2\pi$$

It really surprised me a great deal, not for its simplicity, but because I had never seen such a trick taught in my textbook before!

I want to know what mathematical principle this trick is based on (continuity? I suspect), and on what condition we are able to use it.

Best regards.

---

I have been pondering on this problem for a while, and just now I had a thought as follows.

By Green's formula, $I$ is independent of $\epsilon$ (and even independent of the shape of $\Gamma$ as long as $\Gamma$ is a Jordan curve enclosing the origin and enclosed by $L$). Therefore we can regard $I$ as a constant function w.r.t. $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^{+}$. Then if $\displaystyle\exists\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}I(\epsilon)$, it will be the desired result. So all I need to do is prove the existence of this limit. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral comes from the complex integral 
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } \cos \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right)d\theta }  + i\int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } \sin \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right)d\theta }  \\ 
  &= \int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } \left[ {\cos \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right) - i\sin \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right)} \right]d\theta }  \\ 
  &= \int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } e^{ - i\varepsilon \sin \theta } d\theta }  \\ 
  &= \int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \left( {\cos \theta  + i\sin \theta } \right)} d\theta }  \\ 
  &= \int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon e^{i\theta } } d\theta }  \\ 
  &=  - i\int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{{e^{ - \varepsilon e^{i\theta } } }}{{\varepsilon e^{i\theta } }}i\varepsilon e^{i\theta } d\theta }  \\ 
  &=  - i\int_L {\frac{{e^{ - z} }}{z}dz}  \\ 
  &=  - i\left( {2\pi i} \right) \\ 
  &= 2\pi  
\end{align}
So that $$
\int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } \cos \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right)d\theta } 
=2\pi$$  and $$\int_0^{2\pi } {e^{ - \varepsilon \cos \theta } \sin \left( {\varepsilon \sin \theta } \right)d\theta } =0$$